# How to access methods and properties of WPF control from WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

There is a control created in the library of custom controls that contains ONLY RichTextBox (System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox). It is added to a WinForms form.

The problem is to access its methods and properties.

When using `var rich = elementHost1.Child as System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`, the `rich` variable contains `null`.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what elementHost1.Child actually is.

Comment: @Clemens Its type is WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1

Comment: Ok, you may know what that is. At least it is obvious that the `as` operator returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1

If I understood your explanation correctly, then try this:

```cs
    WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1 control = 
        (WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1) elementHost1.Child;
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox rich = 
        (System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox) control.Content;
```

> System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type "System.Windows.Controls.Grid" to type "System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox"."

Then you did not correctly explain "that contains ONLY RichTextBox".

Need to change the code to take into account the Grid:

```cs
    WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1 control = 
        (WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1) elementHost1.Child;
    System.Windows.Controls.Grid grid = 
        (System.Windows.Controls.Grid) control.Content;
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox rich = 
        (System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox) grid.Children[0];
```

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type "System.Windows.Controls.Grid" to type "System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox"."

Comment: Then the RichTextBox likely is a child of that Grid (or located even deeper down the Visual Tree). A method that recursively enumerates through a Visual's children comes in handy for this kind of task ...

Comment: @vitkuz573, Read the update to my answer.
If this code also does not work, then show the XAML of your UserControl1.

Comment: @vitkuz573, If you only need RichTextBox then I advise you to simplify elementHost1.
Show how you create it and I'll show you how you can change it so that later it would be easier for you to use it.